How torch.Tensor.backward() function works in this situation?
Let's assume that I included the parameters of two models (for example, SAM and U-NET) in a variable called 'joint_parameters', and then set the optimizer as
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(joint_params, lr=1e-5)

And let's say 'sam_loss' is the loss that calculated from the SAM model's output.
What happens to the U-NET model's parameters when I execute
sam_loss.backward()
optimizer.step() 

Does it has any effect on the U-NET's parameters? or nothing happens?
I think nothing will happen to U-NET's parameters but I just wants to make it sure.
